# linq join causing very slow performance / correct way to optimize it

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have join in linq as below

```
IEnumerable < UserATrailViewModel > v1 = from u in useratrailbusiness.GetAllUsers().AsQueryable()
join u1 in userPackageAtrailBusiness.GetAllUsers().AsQueryable()
on u.Uid equals u1.Uid into t1
from subpet in t1.DefaultIfEmpty()
orderby u.CreatedDate descending

select new UserATrailViewModel {

    UserATID = u.UserATID,
    Uid = u.Uid,
    RoleId = u.RoleId,

    FirstName = Md5Decryption.Decrypt(u.FirstName),
    LastName = Md5Decryption.Decrypt(u.LastName),
    Email = u.Email,
    UserName = u.UserName,
    CreatedDate = u.CreatedDate,
    IsActive = u.IsActive,
    CreatedBy = u.CreatedBy,
    ModifiedDate = u.ModifiedDate,
    ModifiedBy = u.ModifiedBy,
    //UniqueGuid = u.UniqueGuid,
    CompanyName = Md5Decryption.Decrypt(u.CompanyName),
    Country = Md5Decryption.Decrypt(u.Country),

    State = Md5Decryption.Decrypt(u.State),
    City = Md5Decryption.Decrypt(u.City),

    Address1 = Md5Decryption.Decrypt(u.Address1),
    Address2 = Md5Decryption.Decrypt(u.Address2),
    PhoneNo = Md5Decryption.Decrypt(u.PhoneNo),
    MobileNo = Md5Decryption.Decrypt(u.MobileNo),
    SrvDTStamp = u.SrvDTStamp,
    ClientCountry = u.ClientCountry,
    App_User = u.App_User,
    Audit_Action = u.Audit_Action,
    FullName = Md5Decryption.Decrypt(u.FirstName) + " " + Md5Decryption.Decrypt(u.LastName),
    ContactNo = Md5Decryption.Decrypt(u.PhoneNo) + " , " + Md5Decryption.Decrypt(u.MobileNo),

    PackageName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.PackageName),
};
```

it is extremely slow as it takes 18 to 24 seconds to fetch the data even for 40 to 50 records. How can I make it faster as it is very much slow.I am not sure whether it is right way to get these data or not.so Any other alternative to this is appreciated as well which can make the process much faster.

Comment: If you profile the database what SQL is being produced? When you run that SQL what does the execution plan look like? The problem here is more likely to do with your database than with your code

Comment: @Jamiec No, his code is having problem look at select statement particalarly `Md5Decryption.Decrypt(u.FirstName)` which is never possible with linq to sql as I believe.

Comment: @Jamiec Agreed, but maybe it has to do with decrypting a lot of fields too

Comment: Wow I didnt even notice that! Md5 *Decryption*. I know its a weak hash but that seems...a bit.... bonkers.

Comment: useratrailbusiness.GetAllUsers().AsQueryable() <=> get all table in memory. You are not in a linq to entities paradigm but in a linq to object. Try to rewrite your query for linq to entities and do processing (like decrypt) on the result of the query.

Comment: yup, it seems as the decryption is causing the problem. Thanks guys. I have to decrypt these fields anyway can you guys please explain how I can achieve it outside this statement may be without using too much lengthy process like loops.

Answer (score 1):

You could start by moving all the calls to the `Md5Decryption.Decrypt()` method to the `UserATrailViewModel` class, either in the constructor or in custom setters. That will make your query more simple as you don't really want the database to do the decrypting.